# Is it possible to import contents from a shared onedrive folder in transloadit?

Tags: transloadit

One of our vendor uses transloadit to import files into their platform. I use OneDrive for Business as a cloud service to maintain our files. I would like to import content from the OneDrive "Shared folder" (shared by my colleague), but I couldn't find any shared folder in the OneDrive folder directory while trying to import the content from the transloadit popup window, but it appears on the actual OneDrive website. Is there any workaround to access the "Shared folder" in the transloadit import window?

I don't want to maintain redundant copies of the same files on multiple accounts.

(I'm not a tech guy, If my question is armature, padrone me.)

Answer (score 0):

I am Florian from Transloadit and I just saw your question here.
In general we do not have a native OneDrive implementation yet. But we are having an official Zapier integration, which offers some support:
https://zapier.com/apps/onedrive/integrations/transloadit

I hope this helps a little.

In case you have further questions, drop us an email at support@transloadit.com